# How to use Google API in a js file?

Tags: javascript, google-api

I want to use Google API inside a js file and how can I use it? I tried to use google.load() directly in the js file but was told that google is not defined. Then I tried to use the following code

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
```

but was told that document is not defined.
What should I do to use google api inside a js file? Thank you.

Here what I want to use is the [Google Feed API](https://developers.google.com/feed/).

The html code I used is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Example
        </title>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head> 

    <body>
        <div>
            <p id="computation_results">please wait, computing … </p>
        </div>
        <script>
            var worker = new Worker('numberworker.js');
            worker.postMessage({first:123,second:456});
            worker.onmessage = function (event)
            {
                alert(event.data);
                document.getElementById('computation_results').textContent = event.data;
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the js file where I want to use the api is

```
// Our callback function, for when a feed is loaded.
function feedLoaded(result) {
if (!result.error) {
    var container = document.getElementById("content");
    container.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
      var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title));
      container.appendChild(div);
    }
  }
}
function OnLoad() {
  var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://www.digg.com/rss/index.xml");
  feed.load(feedLoaded);
}

onmessage = function (event) 
{ 
    var fileref=document.createElement('script');
    var filename="https://www.google.com/jsapi";
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
//  google.load("feeds", "1");
//  google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
    var first=event.data.first; 
    var second=event.data.second; 
    postMessage("Work done! "+ " "+first+" "+second);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and I have edited the question. What I used here is google feed api. @Engineer

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the API before you can use it. Try putting this in your head block:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

To load the feed API, you can then have another script block like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("feeds", "1");
    var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("<<url here>>");
    ...
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry and I have removed it. Thank you. @Derek

Comment: So should I add this in the html file before using it in the js file? I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I would check to make sure your html is validated first, or put up a link to a test file. Any slightest error can cause you to get any number of errors. I tried the following code in a file by itself, wrapped in  tags, and was able to load the api. To load a javascript file using javascript you would use the following

```
var fileref=document.createElement('script');
var filename="https://www.google.com/jsapi";
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
```

Then after it you use the api calls

```
google.load(....)\
```

**EDIT:**

You are using html5 web workers, that use process outside of the browser, to create a script. This is not possible due to html5 workers do not have access to the DOM. http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-threading-html5-web-workers/

You would have to create  it outside of the worker or include in a script element

Comment: Thank you and I have tried to move the code into the html file and it can works. But when I move it into the js file, it still did not work and I was told that document is not defined.

Comment: Have you validated your html? Is there any code or test site that I can look at. Javascript document is based off of the page as a whole. If there are any errors; extra characters in the head or outside the <body> or <head> tags for example; can cause document to be undefined.

Comment: Yes I have checked the html. When the google api and the document are not added to the js file, it works well. But when I was trying to use them, it fails to work. I will paste the code soon, sorry.